# how to write a function for fetching the record by sending only parameters in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 100 tables or can be more than that,I always need to fetch the record all the time in my application from various table.So writing functions for each and every query its not good coding standard.

```
 $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from("table1");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();


    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from("table2");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();


    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from("table1");
    $this->db->where("id",10);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
```

I want the good coding standard for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this code in controller.

```
$data = $this->common_model->getRecords("table_name", "*", array("field1" => $this->input->post('user_name')));
```

This will be your function in model (that is common_model).

```
public function getRecords($table, $fields = '', $condition = '', $order_by = '', $limit = '', $debug = 0) {

            $str_sql = '';
            if (is_array($fields)) {  #$fields passed as array
                $str_sql.=implode(",", $fields);
            } elseif ($fields != "") {   #$fields passed as string
                $str_sql .= $fields;
            } else {
                $str_sql .= '*';  #$fields passed blank
            }

            $this->db->select($str_sql, FALSE);

            if (is_array($condition)) {  #$condition passed as array
                if (count($condition) > 0) {
                    foreach ($condition as $field_name => $field_value) {
                        if ($field_name != '' && $field_value != '') {
                            $this->db->where($field_name, $field_value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if ($condition != "") { #$condition passed as string
                $this->db->where($condition);
            }

            if ($limit != "")
                $this->db->limit($limit);#limit is not blank

            if (is_array($order_by)) {
                $this->db->order_by($order_by[0], $order_by[1]);  #$order_by is not blank
            } else if ($order_by != "") {
                $this->db->order_by($order_by);  #$order_by is not blank
            }


            $this->db->from($table);  #getting record from table name passed
            $query = $this->db->get();

            if ($debug) {
                die($this->db->last_query());
            }
            $error = $this->db->_error_message();
            $error_number = $this->db->_error_number();
            if ($error) {
                $controller = $this->router->fetch_class();
                $method = $this->router->fetch_method();
                $error_details = array(
                    'error_name' => $error,
                    'error_number' => $error_number,
                    'model_name' => 'common_model',
                    'model_method_name' => 'getRecords',
                    'controller_name' => $controller,
                    'controller_method_name' => $method
                );
                $this->common_model->errorSendEmail($error_details);
                redirect(base_url() . 'page-not-found');
            }
            return $query->result_array();
        }
```

I used this code for fetching the record. you just need to pass the table name ,fields name ,the condition and limit.

Answer (score 0):

your codes can actually be in 1 line

```
  $query= $this->db->get('table1')->result_array();

  $query= $this->db->get_where('table1', array('id'=>3,'name'=>'tom'))->result_array();
```

or if you really want a function

```
function getData($table){
    $query=$this->db->get($table)->result_array();
    return $query;

}

$data= getData('table1');
```